# Why is "Unable to pre-dex - Error while signing the application" error happening on Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-signing

**This error** is displayed when signing and publishing **(Build / Generate Signed Apk...)** the program on Android Studio.

- When I run the program without a signature, I have no problem and it
  runs correctly, but if I use the signature file, I will encounter
  this error.

[Stacktrace ScrenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JtsN.jpg)

[Stacktrace ScrenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nblFJ.jpg)

**App build.gradle Codes:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    ...
    implementation 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Not getting! Hi can you share app build.gradle file here

Comment: @PankajKantPatel Yes, I placed the code in your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project has problem with included dependency library.

Replace

compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'

to

```
compile ('com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android'
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer was my question